# Oracle : Combine unique row values into comma-separated string

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a query that returns data like below, need to combine the value column into comma-separated string excluding duplicates and null values.

```
g_name    g_id      v_data    
-----     ----      ------
Test      123        ABC
Test      123        ABC
Test      123        DEG
Test      123        None
Test      123        
Test      123        HIJ
```

Desired output :

```
g_name    g_id      v_data    
-----     ----      ------
Test      123        ABC,DEG,HIJ
```

I have tried using `XMLAGG` but can't remove duplicates and null values.

```
select g_name,
     g_id,
     RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, v_data || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',')
from tblData
group by g_name, g_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pre-filter your rows with a common table expression, then do your string concatenation.

```
with cte1 as (
    select distinct *
    from tblData
    where v_data is not null
)
select g_name,
    g_id,
    RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, v_data || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',')
from cte1
group by g_name, g_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LISTAGG` function:

```
select g_name, g_id, listagg(v_data,',') within group (order by v_data) v_data
from (
  select distinct g_name, g_id, v_data
  from tblData
  where v_data is not null
)
group by g_name, g_id
```

In the inner select, we deal with the `DISTINCT` and `NULL` removal (you could also remove `None` here if you wanted).
The outer query deals with grouping by your name and id and concatenating the values

Comment: LISTAGG is only available Oracle 11g, and im using Oracle 10g :(